# MVC RenderAction inside dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, renderaction

I am hoping someone can assist me. I have a RenderAction inside a dialog so that I can dynamically populate some dropdowns with updated data. Currently, the dialog box won't close after saving when trying to re-render the action.

Here is my partial view that contains the dialog:

```
<div id="beneficiary-add" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-responsive-label" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header modal-header-primary">
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="close">&times;</button>
                <h4 id="modal-responsive-label" class="modal-title">Add Beneficiary</h4>
            </div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("AddBeneficiary", "Clients", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form-add-beneficiary" }))
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ClientId)
                Html.RenderAction("AddBeneficiaryPartial", "Clients", new { id = Model.ClientId });
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the partial that contains the dialog that is being returned by the controller:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table id="table-beneficiaries" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ddd" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>ZIP Code</th>
        <th>Relationship</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.ClientBeneficiaries)
        {
    <tr>
        <td>@item.ClientBeneficiary.LastName</td>
        <td>@item.ClientBeneficiary.FirstName</td>
        <td>@item.ClientBeneficiary.Address</td>
        <td>@item.ClientBeneficiary.City</td>
        <td>@item.ClientBeneficiary.State</td>
        <td>@item.ClientBeneficiary.ZipCode</td>
        <td>@item.Relationship</td>
        <td><a class="edit-beneficiary" data-id="@item.ClientBeneficiary.Id" style="cursor: pointer;">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a class="delete-beneficiary" data-id="@item.ClientBeneficiary.Id" style="cursor: pointer;">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" data-target="#beneficiary-add" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary">Add Beneficiary</button>
@Html.Partial("_BeneficiaryAdd", new EG.Core.ViewModels.BeneficiaryViewModel() { ClientId = Model.Client.Id })
<div id="beneficiary-edit-container"></div>
```

Not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you didn't close your div at the end of 'AddBeneficiaryPartial' view

Comment: It is closed. Maybe I didn't paste it correctly. :-( Thanks.

Comment: Which js library you use to show your modal dialog? May be this library causes a problem?

Comment: It seems to be bombing when I repopulate the model and then try to render the partial again.

Comment: How do you perform rerender action? Are you using ajax or postback?

Comment: Using ajax form submit. Controller returns the partial view and I use jquery to empty the container and return the new results.

Comment: Do you call modal.close action on your modal dialog object?

Comment: I use modal('hide') after a successful ajax call. Currently working on the edit partial to see if it does the same thing.

Comment: For the very beginning try to call modal('hide') before ajax call. If it will work this problem may be caused by DOM inconsistencies after you updated it via Jquery.

Comment: It closed the modal, but it didn't clear out my results and put the new partial in. I'll keep testing and see if it has something to do with my model. Will keep you posted. Thank you!

Comment: What code do you use to update you result? May be it's a good idea to use something like Ajax.BeginForm instead of Html.BeginForm?

Comment: in this case you'll need to set UpdateTargetId in your AjaxOptions object, and all the content inside container with this id will be updated.

Comment: Using Ajax, I get this: A public action method 'AddBeneficiaryPartial' was not found on controller 'EG.Core.Controllers.ClientsController'.

Comment: Okay, I removed the [HttpGet] and it works, but not putting the target in the right place. Getting closer!

Comment: Could you update code in your question to match your new code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61493/discussion-between-agaspher-and-jallen).

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer! I just got it working.